# Average of subquery in GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a table T with columns A & C, from which I would like to retrieve an average count like so:

```
select avg(AC) as AV
from
( 
 select A, count(1) as AC
 from T
 where C = 1
 group by A
)
```

How do I accomplish this in GORM?  GRAILS version 2.2.0  I tried following the documentation but there are no good examples.  I couldn't even get the subquery to work :(

## Update

I was able to get the count portion to work.  Still now sure how to get the average since I don't know how to select from a query.

```
def tc = T.createCriteria()

def tCounts = tc.buildCriteria {
    and {
        eq 'C', 1
    }
    projections {
       groupProperty 'A'
       rowCount('AC')
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added an example in the Update section.  Single entity T with A and C properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is done in HQL. Tested in a grails console with one of my domains:

```
T.executeQuery("""
select avg(count(*))
from T t
where t.c = 1
group by t.a
""")
```

Comment: If you gave an actual example instead of this A C crap I would be able to tell you 100%.

Comment: I tried exactly this approach but failed for me. What is represented by `t.AC`, am I missing anything?

Comment: You did it!  No need for other examples.  @dmahapatro I belive it should be `t`, not `t.AC`

Comment: @Alex It never worked for me. Refer [this sample](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5881030/) which I used in my grails console. Un-comment the creation part in first run and then comment it for subsequent runs. Note my assertions. `Team` represents `T` where `a` and `c` are Integer.

Comment: @Alex Can you also show how it worked for you with your final implementation?

Comment: it worked as you have it in your test, with the exception that I aliased `T t` not `T as t` in your example.  I'm also using Oracle 11gR2.  Maybe this has something to do with the database?

Comment: I'm on Oracle 11g as well.

Comment: I think I know what may be causing your test to fail.  Try adding an PK ID column.  When I look at the generated SQL the `t` inside `count(t)` is substituted with the PK column name

Comment: oh, I just checked.  You don't have to add a PK column.  You can say `count(*)`  I've updated the answer to reflect that

Comment: @Alex Yes verified. This is a particular behavior of Oracle db. I was testing against in-memory db. That small bit of information would have been way more convenient and you would have had your answer from me  way before. I deliberately tested each of the approach against in-memory db and eliminated the cases where it failed. Anyways, you were able to achieve and optimize as it should ideally be.

Comment: Now question for me is "Why this difference in behavior?". Is it the role of the `dialect` to define which functions can be used and which cannot? @JamesKleeh

Comment: The dialect really is just a translator from Hibernate functions to database specific functions. Hibernate can't produce functionality that isn't available on the database itself.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
Lately it was found that in-memory database was restricting to use `avg()` on `count()`. After numerous cross-examination, it was found that with Oracle db actually the below HQL can yield appropriate result and would eradicate the complexity of fetching the rows from db and then calculating the average in Groovy:

```
T.executeQuery("select avg(count(t)) from Team as t where t.c = 1 group by t.a")
```

The problem I was facing with in-memory db is [showcased as a sample](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5881030/).

---

**INIT**
On my first look at the query I thought it can be achieved by using `DetachedCriteria` but `avg` projection can only be applied on domain properties but cannot be applied on `count()`. Same goes with HQL.

You can use combination of `withCriteria` and groovy `collect` to get the average of count of A as:

```
def countOfA = T.withCriteria{
    eq 'c', 1
    projections{
        count 'a'
        groupProperty 'a'
    }
}?.collect{it?.first()}

def averageCount = countOfA ? (countOfA.sum() / countOfA.size()) : 0
```

Comment: Is there a way to project from an aliased criteria?  It's really simple in SQL to select from another select statement.  I'm surprised that this can't even be done in HQL

Comment: @Alex I mentioned your predicament in first few lines of the answer. HQL and criteria, aliases work on domain class properties. Projections can only be applied to properties of domain class. You cannot project like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5879787/). BTW, what is the problem in getting the average using groovy way, it is simple arithmetic on the result set? If you still feel GORM or HQL incompetent then you can very well jump to SQL. Grab Hibernate Session  from `SessionFactory`, `createSQLQuery`, then `execute`.

Comment: thanks.  I accepted your answer.  The problem is that if there are a lot of records in the count query then a lot of data has to transfer from the database.  It's more efficient to do the average on the database.

Comment: @Alex I strongly agree. But there was no way for me to get it from the query when tested against in-memory db. Glad HQL worked for oracle db. More importantly, query is optimized. Now question for me is "Why this difference in behavior?". Is it the role of the dialect which defines which functions can be used and which cannot?