# JPA/Hibernate Subselection-Avoidance

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, average

So I should like to execute a query like this in JPA that will allow me to get the average number of Bs associated with an A:

```
SELECT avg(c)
FROM (
    SELECT A.id, count(*) AS c
    FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
    GROUP BY A.id
)
```

Unfortunately, HQL does not support this. (HQL subqueries can only occur in the SELECT or WHERE clauses.)

Is it possible to rewrite the above to an HQL-compatible query? If so, how? And if not, how would I go about retrieving the information I need?

Comment: have you visited this link; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666843/average-of-subquery-in-gorm

Comment: JPQL can only have subqueries in WHERE and HAVING clauses actually

Comment: @Godwin: I have now, thank you. However, the solution therein, "SELECT avg(count(\*)) FROM A a JOIN B b WITH a.id = b.id GROUP BY a.id" always returns 0.0 - which it shouldn't. I could get the counts via "SELECT count(\*) FROM A a JOIN B b WITH ..." and then average over the resulting list of Longs myself, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution.